# TypeError: Cannot read property 'animated' of undefined in Discord.JS when I call new Discord.MessageReaction(client, data, message);

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to build a command in DiscordJS for a bot I am making which makes a poll upon the command `\poll <title> <option 1> <option 2> [options 3-9]`. Creating the poll runs fine, but then when the poll is sent in a polls channel, it throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'animated' of undefined` when I create a `Discord.MessageReaction` with the `new Discord.MessageReaction(client, data, message);` constructor. Here is my code:

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {return}
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
  switch (args[0]) {
      case 'poll':
          //message.reply('sorry, poll is currently in development.')
          //break
          let waitingonYes = false
          let shouldicontinue = true
          if (args.length <= 3) {if (args[1] !== 'yes') {message.reply('missing arguments!');} break}
          if(args[1] === 'end') {
            if(polls[toString(args[1])] !== null, pollMsgs[toString(args[1])] !== null) {
              polls.splice(polls.indexOf(toString(args[1])), 1)
              pollMsgs.splice(pollMsgs.indexOf(toString(args[1])), 1)
              message.channel.send('Ok, ending poll number ' + args[1] + '.')
            }
            else {
              message.reply('that poll doesn\'t exist!')
            }
          }
          if(args[1] === 'yes', waitingonYes === true) {
            waitingonYes = false
            shouldicontinue = true
          }
          if(args[1] === 'cancel', waitingonYes === true) {
            message.channel.send('Ok, canceling poll.')
            waitingonYes = false
            clearInterval(whatwhydoessetintervalbreakevery2seconds)
            shouldicontinue = false
          }
          else {
            pollmessage = message.content.toString()
            waitingonYes = false
            shouldicontinue = true
            message.reply('ok, making a poll with these settings: ')
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('Poll')
              .addField('Title:', `${args[1]}`)
              .addFields(
                { name: 'Option :one::', value: `${args[2]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :two::', value: `${args[3]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :three::', value: `${args[4]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :four::', value: `${args[5]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :five::', value: `${args[6]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :six::', value: `${args[7]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :seven::', value: `${args[8]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :eight::', value: `${args[9]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :nine::', value: `${args[10]}`, inline: true },
              )
            message.channel.send(embed)
            message.channel.send(`Type \'${PREFIX}poll yes\' to confirm the poll. Please note that to avoid crashing this bot checks for this every second, no faster.`)
            waitingonYes = true
            let whatwhydoessetintervalbreakevery2seconds = setInterval(function() {
              if (waitingonYes === false) {
                clearInterval(whatwhydoessetintervalbreakevery2seconds)
              }
            }, 1000)
            if (shouldicontinue === false) {break}
            let thing = message.guild.channels.cache.get('858821179192377345').send(embed)
            new Discord.MessageReaction(bot, ':one:', thing)
            //thing.react('one')
            //print(channel.id)
            //if (shouldicontinue === false) {break}
            //message.guild.channels.cache.get() 
            //var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(
            //  .addTitle()
            //)
            //message.channel.send()
            console.log('yay it works lol')
            break
          }
    }
  }
  }
)
```

Using the `message.react()` function results in the error `message.react() is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.channel.type === 'dm') return;
  let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
  if(message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) {
  switch (args[0]) {
      case 'poll':
          let waitingonYes = false
          let shouldicontinue = true
          if (args.length <= 3) {if (args[1] !== 'yes') {message.reply('missing arguments!');} break}
          if(args[1] === 'end') {
            if(polls[toString(args[1])] !== null, pollMsgs[toString(args[1])] !== null) {
              polls.splice(polls.indexOf(toString(args[1])), 1)
              pollMsgs.splice(pollMsgs.indexOf(toString(args[1])), 1)
              message.channel.send('Ok, ending poll number ' + args[1] + '.')
            }
            else {
              message.reply('that poll doesn\'t exist!')
            }
          }
          if(args[1] === 'yes', waitingonYes === true) {
            waitingonYes = false
            shouldicontinue = true
          }
          if(args[1] === 'cancel', waitingonYes === true) {
            message.channel.send('Ok, canceling poll.')
            waitingonYes = false
            clearInterval(whatwhydoessetintervalbreakevery2seconds)
            shouldicontinue = false
          }
          else {
            pollmessage = message.content.toString()
            waitingonYes = false
            shouldicontinue = true
            message.reply('ok, making a poll with these settings: ')
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle('Poll')
              .addField('Title:', `${args[1]}`)
              .addFields(
                { name: 'Option :one::', value: `${args[2]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :two::', value: `${args[3]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :three::', value: `${args[4]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :four::', value: `${args[5]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :five::', value: `${args[6]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :six::', value: `${args[7]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :seven::', value: `${args[8]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :eight::', value: `${args[9]}`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Option :nine::', value: `${args[10]}`, inline: true },
              )
            message.channel.send(embed)
            message.channel.send(`Type \'${PREFIX}poll yes\' to confirm the poll. Please note that to avoid crashing this bot checks for this every second, no faster.`)
            waitingonYes = true
            let whatwhydoessetintervalbreakevery2seconds = setInterval(function() {
              if (waitingonYes === false) {
                clearInterval(whatwhydoessetintervalbreakevery2seconds)
              }
            }, 1000)
            if (shouldicontinue === false) {break}
            message.guild.channels.cache.get('858821179192377345').send(embed).then(thing => thing.react('1️⃣'));
            //print(channel.id)
            //if (shouldicontinue === false) {break}
            //message.guild.channels.cache.get() 
            //var embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed(
            //  .addTitle()
            //)
            //message.channel.send()
            console.log('yay it works lol')
            break
          }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It works, but then it throws the error `Unknown Emoji`

Comment: Replace the `:one:` with 1️⃣

Comment: Another quick question: how would I add multiple reactions to the message?

Comment: `message.guild.channels.cache.get('858821179192377345').send(embed).then(thing => {
       thing.react('1️⃣'); thing.react('2️⃣');
});`